# Filling and sorting parallel arrays from single user input

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, parallel-processing, substring

I have to accept a single user input of a string and an int ten times, separate them at the space into two parallel arrays. I then have to sort them, find average, etc. Everything I have found on parallel arrays has two different inputs for the string and int. How can I separate the single input into the two arrays?

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    //double[] gradeArray = new double[10];

//String[] nameArray = new String[10];


    String name = " "; //name substring
    String num = " "; //int substring
    String s = " "; //input String
    int grade = Integer.parseInt(num); //parsing the numerical string to an int

    int x = s.indexOf(' '); //index of " " space

    name = s.substring(0, x);
    num =s.substring(x + 1);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] gradeArray = new int[10];

    String[] nameArray = new String[10];
    //looping to gather 10 user inputs
    for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++){
        System.out.println("Input Student name and grade: ");
        s = input.nextLine();

        //not sure how to sepearate String s into String name and String num
    }


    System.out.println("Highest Grade: " + Grades.highestGrade(gradeArray));
    System.out.println("Lowest Grade: " + Grades.lowestGrade(gradeArray));
    System.out.println("Class Average: " + Grades.classAverage(gradeArray));

    for(int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++){
        System.out.print(nameArray[i] + ", ");
        System.out.print(gradeArray[i]);
        System.out.println();

    //  System.out.print(sort());



    }
```

Comment: will there be a space in between the name and the grade? as in `John 90` or `Michael 78` etc.. ?

Comment: yes, exactly. int x is the index of the space in the string

Comment: see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I separate the single input into the two arrays?

First, we will use the already declared array of `double` to store the grades.

```
double[] gradeArray = new double[10];
```

Second, we will use the already declared array of `String` to store the names.

```
String[] nameArray = new String[10];
```

Now, going on to the `for` loop, we can use the [`String#split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method to separate the `name` and the `grade` on the delimiter `" "` considering that there will be whitespace between the `name` and `grade` as you've mentioned.

```
for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++){
      System.out.println("Input Student name and grade: ");
      s = input.nextLine();
      String[] tempArray = s.split(" ");
      nameArray[k] = tempArray[0]; // store name to nameArray
      gradeArray[k] = Double.parseDouble(tempArray[1]);  // store grade to gradeArray
}
```

Comment: How would I parse it from String to int in the for loop?

Comment: @user3403708 glad it helped ^^ .